# send cookies from subdomain

Tags: cross-domain, setcookie, httpcookie

I'm building a web app that uses http only cookie sent by the backend for session data. Now my backend is hosted at xyz.domain.com

My client side is domain.com (note - m not using www.domain.com )

Now when the client receives cookie , the browser doesn't save it. In crome i saw the cookie isn't first party.

After doing a bit of research i figured out to send cookie with domain - .domain.com 
Tried that. Didn't work.

How should this be done.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should set domain attribute as your domain: 
`domain= .domain.com`

If you can say which language are you working on and what have you tried so far, people may provide some good examples.

Comment: m working on spring boot to create my http only cookie and on the client side m using angular js

Comment: cookie is being saved in firefox but not in Crome